# How to combine values in a column by group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe as input read from excel:

```
  Name    Data
0    A   green
1    A    blue
2    A  yellow
3    A   green
4    B   green
5    B   green
6    B     red
7    C  violet
8    C     red
9    C   white
```

Desired output:

```
  Name               Data
0    A  blue;green;yellow
1    B          green;red
2    C   red;violet;white
```

I tried the following, both gave errors

```
pivot_df = df.pivot(index = df.columns[0], columns =  df.columns[1])  ## Gives --> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
pivot_table_df = df.pivot_table(index = df.columns[0], columns =  df.columns[1])  ## gives --> pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# convert type to string you can also use .astype(str) which is vectorized
df["Data"] = df["Data"].map(str)
# group data by name, set index parameters false otherwise you will have "Name" as an index. Theoretically you could simply do ["Data"].apply(list) but aggregate is more scalable in case other columns will be added later on.
df = df.groupby(["Name"], as_index=False).aggregate({"Data": set})
# df["Data"] now contains a set, we want to get a ordered, concatenated string with the delimiter ";" out of it, therefore we use ";".join() to join a list to a string. I use .map which is not vectorized, and this part is therefore probably up for improvement.
df["Data"] = df["Data"].map(lambda x: ";".join(sorted(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is -

```
df.groupby(['Name'])['Data'].apply(set).apply(';'.join).reset_index()
```

```
  Name               Data
0    A  yellow;green;blue
1    B          red;green
2    C   red;violet;white
```

Comment: when the values in the Data column of the input dataframe are numbers, it gave me "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found". How do I modify the code if the values in the Data column of the input dataframe are numbers?:<br/> <br/>-Thanks.

Comment: just do ```df = df.astype(str)``` then run this code

Answer (score 0):

- Since the `'Data'` column can contain numbers (as stated in comments), it's better to set the `dtype` as `str`, because [`.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is a `str` method, and it's more efficient then using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) inside the lambda function (e.g. `map(str, set(x))`).
- Use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `'Data'` and [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) a function

  - `lambda x: ';'.join(sorted(set(x))))`

    - Each group contains non-unique values, so use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set), because a `set` may only contain unique values.
    - Use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) if you want the result in order, otherwise replace `sorted(set(x))` with `set(x)`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
data = {'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
        'Data': ['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'violet', 'red', 'white', 3, 3, 3]}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert the Data column to str type
df.Data = df.Data.astype('str')

# groupby name and apply the function
dfg = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Data'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(sorted(set(x))))

# display(dfg)
  Name                 Data
0    A  3;blue;green;yellow
1    B          3;green;red
2    C   3;red;violet;white
```

Comment: I like the solution, it helps me understand the coding more.  However, when I print the variable dfg, i no longer have column "Name"...but i figure it it.  I set as_index=True, and added .reset_index() at the end.  I got this idea from Akshay's solution.  Thanks.